# Use matplotlib to plot scikit learn linear regression results

Tags: matplotlib, scikit-learn, linear-regression

How can you plot the linear regression results from `scikit learn` after the analysis to see the "testing" data (real values vs. predicted values) at the end of the program? The code below is close but I believe it is missing a scaling factor.

input:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like # temp fix
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
from pandas_datareader import data, wb
from datetime import date
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation, svm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = yf.download('MMM', start = date (2012, 1, 1), end = date (2018, 1, 1) , progress = False)
df_low = df[['Low']] # create a new df with only the low column
forecast_out = int(5) # predicting some days into future
df_low['low_prediction'] = df_low[['Low']].shift(-forecast_out) # create a new column based on the existing col but shifted some days

X_low = np.array(df_low.drop(['low_prediction'], 1))
X_low = preprocessing.scale(X_low) # scaling the input values

X_low_forecast = X_low[-forecast_out:] # set X_forecast equal to last 5 days
X_low = X_low[:-forecast_out] # remove last 5 days from X

y_low = np.array(df_low['low_prediction'])
y_low = y_low[:-forecast_out]

X_low_train, X_low_test, y_low_train, y_low_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X_low, y_low, test_size = 0.2)

clf_low = LinearRegression() # classifier
clf_low.fit(X_low_train, y_low_train) # training

confidence_low = clf_low.score(X_low_test, y_low_test) # testing

print("confidence for lows: ", confidence_low)
forecast_prediction_low = clf_low.predict(X_low_forecast)
print(forecast_prediction_low)

plt.figure(figsize = (17,9))
plt.grid(True)
plt.plot(X_low_test, color = "red")
plt.plot(y_low_test, color = "green")
plt.show()
```

image:

[image]

Comment: I think you have just plotted the test data, x (`X_low_test`) and y (`y_low_test`) separately.  What you have to do is to predict new y values based on the `y_low_test`, like: `X_low_predicted = clf_low.predict(y_low_test)`. After that, plot the test set on predicted values of test set by `plt.plot(X_low_test, y_low_test, label='real'); plt.plot(X_low_predicted, y_low_test, label='predicted'); plt.legend()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You plot `y_test` and `X_test`, while you should plot `y_test` and `clf_low.predict(X_test)` instead, if you want to compare target and predicted.

*BTW, `clf_low` in your code is not a classifier, it is a regressor. It's better to use the alias `model` instead of `clf`.*